# Merge files with AWK while adding separators before and after

Tags: awk

I am attempting to do the following, using AWK:

- Read a series of files from a folder.
- Merge all of them into a single file.
- While doing that, I want to place a separator at the beginning *and the end* of every file (actually a block of code, opening and closing tags, but in this example I use a simple separator for clarity).

What I want to see in my output:

```
--Separator : Beginning of File--
  ((Content of file1.txt))
--Separator : End of File--
--Separator : Beginning of File--
  ((Content of file2.txt))
--Separator : End of File--
--Separator : Beginning of File--
  ((Content of file3.txt))
--Separator : End of File--
```

etc...

I have this code snippet, that works for the "Beginning of File" separator:

```
INPUT="../folder/*.txt"
OUPUT="../output.txt"

awk 'FNR==1{print "--Separator : Beginning of File--"}{print}' $INPUT > $OUTPUT
```

Now I'm trying to figure out the next step: detect the end of each file, and put a separator there.

I found a couple of examples that work with END for single file operations, but they only detect the last line *of the last file*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU awk, simply

```
awk 'BEGINFILE { print "--Separator : Beginning of File--" } ENDFILE { print "--Separator : End of File--" } 1' file1 file2 file3
```

Readably formatted:

```
BEGINFILE { print "--Separator : Beginning of File--" }
ENDFILE   { print "--Separator : End of File--" }
1
```

Of which the first two lines seem fairly self-explanatory; `BEGINFILE` and `ENDFILE` are GNU-specific conditions that apply at the beginning and end of a processed file, respectively. The last is an idiomatic way to print lines unchanged. `1` means true, so this condition applies to all lines, and without an associated action, the default action -- printing -- is performed for them.

POSIX-conformingly:

```
awk 'BEGIN { start = "--Separator : Beginning of File--"; end = "--Separator : End of File--"; print start } FNR == 1 && FNR != NR { print end; print start } { print } END { print end }' file1 file2 file3
```

Readably formatted:

```
BEGIN {
  # In the beginning, put the separators in variables so we don't have to
  # repeat ourselves
  start = "--Separator : Beginning of File--"
  end   = "--Separator : End of File--"

  # and print the first beginning separator
  print start
}

# For the first line of all files (FNR == 1) except that of the first
# file (in the first file, the file record number FNR is equal to the
# overall record number NR, so FNR != NR tests for this)
FNR == 1 && FNR != NR { 
  # print the end separator for the previous file
  # and the start separator for this one.
  print end
  print start
}

# print all lines unchanged (no condition means it applies unconditionally)
{ print }

END {
  # and in the end, print the last end separator.
  print end
}
```

Comment: Right. For the OP - the non-gawk solution might behave undesirably if you have any empty input files since it would simply act as if they weren't present rather than adding the start/end separators with nothing in between. Is that a concern?

Comment: Awesome! I'm running awk on Mac OSX, so the second version is working for me.

Comment: @Wintermute – I'm tempted to add some line returns to your code examples, in order to make more evident what they do. In their current shape the lines are too long to be displayed in full. I believe those are very good examples to help a beginner understand how awk works.

Comment: Yeah, not a bad idea. I put in some comments while I was at it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not tied to awk, it's very simple in the shell:

```sh
for file in ../folder/*.txt; do
    echo "--start"
    cat "$file"
    echo "--end"
done > ../output.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a great working alternative indeed. I'm going to do several regex replacements inside those files, that's why awk seemed the most appropriate tool.

Comment: Agreed. If the start/end separators are fairly "dumb", you could replace `cat` with `awk` in the for-loop